# use string expansion in exim4's authenticator

Tags: exim, exim4

I need to extract a valid email address like a@example.com in exim4's authenticator, here is what I did:

gmail_login:
    driver = plaintext
    public_name = LOGIN
    hide client_send = : ${reduce{${addresses:$h_from:}}{}{${if eq{$value}{}{$item}{$value}}}}  : my password

the string has been tested under exim -bem , and it's working, but when put under client_send option, I always got error:

smarthost T=remote_msa defer (0): expansion of "${reduce{${addresses" failed in       gmail_login authenticator: "${addresses" is not a known operator (or a } is missing in a variable reference)

what I'm missing here? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Auth occurs before any data available and there is no headers to extract addresses from.

Comment: thanks, ended up to use this:client_send = : $sender_address_local_part\N@sample.com\N : pass